# Verificar form ya abierto

Tags: c#

Supongamos que instancio un form nuevo en un boton, por ej :

```
form1 form = new form1();
form.show();
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al darle al botón nuevamente, no se abra otro form, y me detecte que ya hay un form abierto?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Usa el patron Singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer todos los forms abiertos y verificar si ya está dentro de esa collección o no

```
foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (OpenForm.Name == "miFormulario")
    {
      //form ya está abierto
    }
}
```